# Boot time contribution from a set of Kernel Driver modules

Tags: linux-device-driver

I wanted to profile/Measure time contributed by set of kernel module drivers to boot time in Android Linux.

Say i have bunch of 20 Drivers that we own for our multimedia sub-system, each of them has corresponding probe and bind calls implemented. Based on Board configurations some Drivers will be bind and some are not.

I wanted to enquire if there is any tools already available in linux kernel, that can illustrate how much time each driver took while boot-up.

Appreciate your help on this. (else i would have to explicitly call timer KPI for each driver bind call and print them after bind successful.)

I came to know we can enable ftrace & perf. But am not familiar using them. Still exploring more on this.

Comment: Add `initcall_debug` to the kernel command line. Read dmesg.

Comment: Looks like it prints timing info only for __init, But for me i need time consumed for Driver Bind to complete (which in-turn contributes for kernel Boot time).

Note:- All my drivers are Dynamic Loadable Kernel Modules.

Comment: Have you checked Kernel Shark: https://kernelshark.org/?

Comment: Also: https://docs.kernel.org/trace/boottime-trace.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Ftrace` with timestamp enabled to trace the time required for
bind/unbind or any other kernel function getting executed.

Ftrace is a tracing utility built directly into the Linux kernel. Just turn on these CONFIGS in kernel:

```
CONFIG_FUNCTION_TRACER
CONFIG_FUNCTION_GRAPH_TRACER
CONFIG_STACK_TRACER
CONFIG_DYNAMIC_FTRACE
```

Your Ftrace output should look something like this. Check the TIMESTAMP column

[image]

More details on Ftrace can be found in [kernel.org here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.0/trace/ftrace.html)